# Find number of occurrences of a partial string in a single column using multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I've a sheet "Employee_log" which contains the details of everyday log in a single string in column A. For example:

```
A1 : EMP1~EMP2~JOB1~JOB2...
A2 : EMP1~EMP3~JOB1~JOB3...
A3 : EMP2~EMP3~JOB2~JOB3...
```

Now I want the number of occurrences of `EMP1` and `JOB1` from this column and populate into another sheet "Ind_Detail":

I'm using, but it's not working properly,:

```
Set DSht = Worksheets("Employee_log")

Dsht. Activate  

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ind_Detail").Cells(1, "A") =CountIfs(Range("A:A"), _
                                              "EMP1", Range("A:A"), "JOB1")

Set DSht = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the criteria in wildcard characters to count if a *'string in a string'* occurs.

```
with Worksheets("Employee_log")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ind_Detail").Cells(1, "A") = _
      application.CountIfs(.columns(1), "*EMP1*", .columns(1), "*JOB1*")
end with
```

I've also blocked the worksheet into a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) so that the ranges (e.g. `.Columns(1)` in the sample) could be localized to the Employee_log worksheet. Your sample of `Range("A:A")` left the definition of the parent worksheet ambiguous.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: is Countifs a member of the application object? didnt know that, thought we have to use WorksheetFunction

Comment: Pretty much any worksheet function can be called with just Application. I very rarely use the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) but I use worksheet functions all the time.

Comment: yeah, it does not show up with intellisense though. Thx for the info

Comment: @SouravSarkar - [Glad you got sorted out](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

CountIfs is a WorkSheet function, it cannot be used directly in VBA. Either write your formula directly in the destination cell:

```
=CountIfs(Employee_log!A:A, "*EMP1*", Employee_log!A:A, "*JOB1*")
```

or, in VBA, use the WorksheetFunction object to access Worksheet functions:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ind_Detail").Cells(1, "A") =WorkSheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "*EMP1*", Range("A:A"), "*JOB1*")
```

EDIT: added wildcards as in Jeeped's answer